# Form of the divisors of a number (Prime Factorization). Is this algorithm-based proof correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I am trying to proof the following result:

> For a number $n$ whose prime number decomposition is $p_1^{\alpha _1} ... p_m^{\alpha _m}$. Every divisor of $n$ has the form $p_1^{\beta _1} ... p_m^{\beta _m}$ with $0 \leq \beta _i \leq \alpha_i$, for all $1 \leq i \leq m$.

Proving that every number of the form $p_1^{\beta _1} ... p_m^{\beta _m}$ is a divisor of $n$ is quite easy.

For the converse part, I have a sort of algorithm (which stands as a proof I guess) but I have some trouble in the formulation.

Let $d$ be a divisor of $n$. We write $n$ in the following alternating form: $n=p_1 ...p_{r}$ (where $r=\Omega (n)$ is the number of prime factors with multiplicity).

- if $d= 1$, we're done with $\beta _i = 0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m$
- if not, $d$ has a unique prime number decomposition. In particular, there exists a prime number $p$ dividing $d$. So, $p\mid n$ and we conclude that $\exists {j_1}, 1\leq {j_1} \leq r$ such as $p = p_{j_1}$

Then, we consider the number $\frac{d}{p_{j_1}}$, there are two cases:

- either $\frac{d}{p_{j_1}} = 1$, in that case, the algorithm is finished and we have $d=p_{j_1}$ with $p_{j_1}$ being one of the prime numbers appearing in the decomposition of $n=p_1 ...p_{r}$
- either $\frac{d}{p_{j_1}} > 1$, in which case $\frac{d}{p_{j_1}}$ has a unique prime number decomposition. In particular there exists a prime number $p$ (not necessarily distrinct from $p_{j_1}$) dividing $\frac{d}{p_{j_1}}$. So, $p$ divides $\frac{n}{p_{j_1}}$ and hence, $\exists j_2 , 1\leq j_2 \leq r, j_2\neq j_1$ such as $p=p_{j_2}$

Then, we consider the number $\frac{d}{p_{j_1}p_{j_2}}$, there are two cases:

- either $\frac{d}{p_{j_1}p_{j_2}} = 1$, in that case, the algorithm is finished and we have $d=p_{j_1}p_{j_2}$ with $p_{j_1}p_{j_2}$ being two of the prime numbers appearing in the decomposition of $n=p_1 ...p_{r}$
- either $\frac{d}{p_{j_1}p_{j_2}} > 1$, in which case $\frac{d}{p_{j_1}p_{j_2}}$ has a unique prime number decomposition. In particular there exists a prime number $p$ dividing $\frac{d}{p_{j_1}p_{j_2}}$. So, $p$ divides $\frac{n}{p_{j_1}p_{j_2}}$ and hence, $\exists j_3 , 1\leq j_3 \leq r, j_3 \neq j_2\neq j_1 $ such as $p=p_{j_3}$

The algorithm may stop at any $j_s$ with $s\leq r$.

The farthest the algorithm can go is at the point where we reach $p_{j_r}$, the last prime number in the permutation defined by $(j_1,...,j_r)$. In that case, since we are out of prime numbers in the list $(p_1, ...,p_r)$ we have that $\frac{d}{p_{j_1}... p_{j_r}} \mid 1$ (since all the prime numbers of $n=p_1 ...p_{r}$ are present in the denominator). Whence, $d = p_1 ... p_r$

---

I wonder if my proof is Ok. Specifically, I wonder whether it could be shortened by considering in the decomposition of $d$ his smallest prime divisor.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Easier: let $~p~$ be a prime number such that $~p \not\in \{ ~p_1, ~\cdots, ~p_m~\}. ~$  Let $~d~$ be any divisor of $~n.~$  Assume that $~p ~| ~d.~$  This implies that $~p~$ divides $~n.~$  This implies that $~p~$ is part of the prime decomposition of $~n.~$  This generates a contradiction, because the prime decomposition of $~n~$ is unique.

Comment: Continuation of previous comment.  Suppose (for example) that $~\left(p_1\right)^r~$ divides some divisor $~d~$ of $~n,~$ where $~r > \beta_1.~$  Then $~\left(p_1\right)^r~$ divides $~n.~$  Similar to the previous comment, again you have a contradiction, because the prime factorization of $~n~$ is unique.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: The natural inductive proof is to handle one prime power factor then recurse on the rest, and we can do this more generally for computing gcds as in the linked dupe (OP is special case $\,d\mid n\!\iff\! d = \gcd(d,n)\ \ $